# How to evaluate and plot symbolic variable in a symbolic function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, plot, signals, symbolic-math

I want to create a symbolic function with three variables: `x` is a vector and `s` and `m` are scalars. Then I want to plot the function using `m` and `s` as 0 and 1, and `x` spanning the interval `[-10, 10]`. I tried the following:

```
syms x m s
%x=
y(x)=((1/(s*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-1/2*((x-m)/s)^2))
m=0
s=1
yx=subs(y)
y
yx
fplot(linspace(-10,10),yx)
```

The plot seems weird. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong syntax to call [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html). Just call it like so:

```
fplot(yx);
```

This will use the default x range of `[-5 5]`. If you want to change the x range, add a 2-element vector argument in the call to `fplot`, like so:

```
fplot(yx, [-10 10]);  % Plots over the range [-10 10]
```

When you put `linspace(...)` as the first argument, MATLAB appears to interpret it as if you're trying to use the 2-argument calling syntax `fplot(funx, funy)`, which expects both the inputs to be [parametric functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html#inputarg_funx) (which they aren't).

Comment: wow that was right !! but why the function choosed the interval by itself?

Comment: @MouadSama: Did you look at the docs? It says clearly that the default x range used by `fplot` is `[-5 5]`.

Comment: thank you very much
what if i wanted my interval to be -10,10